# Chart.js minimal width of Chart with scrollable overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css, chart.js

I am making a website so me and my friends can compare some stats. I am using Chart.js to show these stats. The overall website is made using Bootstrap.
I noticed that when a lot of users are added the bars just become smaller to fit everything on the screen, however I would like the bars to remain a minimal size and overflow off the screen when that minimum is reached. This overflow should still be scrollable however.

Is there any way this could be accomplished?

HTML (inside the container div inside the body):

```
<div class="row"> 
    <canvas id="stats" height="200"></canvas>
</div><br>
```

(I noticed the height doesn't do much)

JavaScript:

```
new Chart(document.getElementById('stats').getContext('2d'), {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: usernames,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'stats1',
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(158, 0, 0)',
            borderColor: 'rgb(135, 0, 0)',
            data: [10, 43]
        }, {
            label:'stats2',
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(0, 38, 120)',
            borderColor: 'rgb(0, 28, 89)',
            data: [10, 43]
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                display: true,
                ticks: {
                    suggestedMin: 0
                }
            }]
        },
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Stats'
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess your best bed is making use of this plugin to be able to scroll your chart.
https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-zoom